# Pyinstaller / Django - pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'django-omnibus' distribution was not found

Tags: python, django, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an installer for a django website that uses the [django-omnibus](https://github.com/moccu/django-omnibus) module.

My Pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller --name djangosite manage.py
```

The Pyinstaller command runs to completion.

Trying to run the web server using

```
djangosite.exe runserver localhost:8000
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
  File "django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
  File "django\core\management\__init__.py", line 312, in execute
  File "django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
  File "django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
  File "django\apps\config.py", line 86, in create
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
  File "c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-vxcefe\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "omnibus\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 561, in get_distribution
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 441, in get_provider
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 962, in require
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 849, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'django-omnibus' distribution was not found and is required by the application manage returned -1
```

If I remove all django-omnibus code, the site works fine (except for the my websocket functionality obviously). Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to add a hook.py file for `django-omnibus` and add the `--additional-hooks-dir=.` flag to the pyinstaller command.

#### hook-omnibus.py

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata, collect_data_files

datas = copy_metadata('django-omnibus')
datas += collect_data_files('omnibus')
```

Similar answer here:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1713

Comment: Got the same `DistributionNotFound` error with `pyqrcode`, using PyInstaller 3.2.1. Adding to `hiddenimports` did not seem to work, but adding a hook file, as described above, did work (`hook-pyqrcode.py`). Did not need `collect_data_files` in my case. I set the `hookspath` argument in the spec file: `Analysis(..., hookspath=['path-to-hook'], ...)`, instead of using the `--additional-hooks-dir`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late reply, but I had a similar issue with **django-user-accounts** - `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'django-user-accounts' distribution was not found`

I was directed here when searching for a fix. I solved the issue with the following addition to settings.py - hopefully helps someone else.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sites',
    ...
]
```